# Numpy 2D array indexing by other 2D along specific axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array:

```
>>> in_arr = np.array([[1,2],[4,3]])
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 3]])
```

and I find the sorted indices by columns to yield another 2D array:

```
>>> col_sort = np.argsort(in_arr, axis=1)
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

I would like to know the efficient numpy slice to index the first by the second:

```
>>> redordered_in_arr = np.*SOME_SLICE_METHOD*(in_arr, col_sort, axis=1)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

The intention is to then perform a (more complicated) function on the array by column, e.g.:

```
>>> arr_with_function = reordered_in_arr ** np.array([1,2])
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 16]])
```

and return the elements to their original position in the array

```
>>> return_order = np.argsort(col_sort, axis=1)
>>> redordered_in_arr = np.*SOME_SLICE_METHOD*(arr_with_function, return_order, axis=1)
array([[1, 4],
       [16, 3]])
```

Ok so thinking about it as I type I might just use apply_over_axis, but I would still like know how to the above efficiently in case it is of value later..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do all those operations in-place then you don't need `argsort()`. Numpy supports in-place operations in such situations:

```
In [12]: in_arr = np.array([[1,2],[4,3]])

In [13]: in_arr.sort(axis=1)

In [14]: in_arr **= [1, 2]

In [15]: in_arr
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 3, 16]])
```

But if you need the indices of the sorted items you can get the expected result with a simple indexing.

```
In [18]: in_arr[np.arange(2)[:,None], col_sort]
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: if the function is more complicated than exponent, i.e. it is non-linear function of the difference between columns can this method still be employed? Actually I'll go and test it now.. thanks

Comment: @Attack68 If you have more operations than just a power you can always do them separately and then reassign the result. The only problem with this approach might be consuming the memory when your arrays are so big that one or two copy of it can gobble up the memory. In that case you can use `ndarray.view` or change the dtype to the lower as possible lr maybe another methods which do not fit into a comment. Nevertheless if you thought that you really  can't use in-place operations you can ask another question regard it.